# Make search bar redirect results to bing

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, redirect

I am trying to make a site that has a search bar that redirects to bing. For example: When I type "The color blue" it redirects the page to http://www.bing.com/search?q=the+color+blue. I would like to use the same method as lmgtfy.

Comment: great. what have you tried?

Comment: Honestly nothing, I am thinking it can be done with PHP using variables somehow

Edit: I also do not mind doing the work, I am just not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the following code in a file for an easy example of what you're trying to accomplish.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
  <div>
  <h1>Page redirects to a bing search</h1>

  <form method="GET" action="http://www.bing.com/search"> 
  <input type="text" name="q" id="q" value="enter your search here">
  <input type="submit" value="Lookup">
  </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is PHP parsing needed?

Comment: you're right, in this case it isn't; answer edited.